# How does numpy's memmap copy-on-write mode work?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm confused by how numpy's `memmap` handles changes to data when using copy-on-write (`mmap_mode=c`). Since nothing is written to the original array on disk, I'm expecting that it has to store all changes in memory, and thus could run out of memory if you modify every single element. To my surprise, it didn't.

I am trying to reduce my memory usage for my machine learning scripts which I run on a shared cluster (the less mem each instance takes, the more instances I can run at the same time). My data are very large numpy arrays (each > 8 Gb). My hope is to use `np.memmap` to work with these arrays with small memory (<4Gb available).

However, each instance might modify the data differently (e.g. might choose to normalize the input data differently each time). This has implications for storage space. If I use the `r+` mode, then normalizing the array in my script will permanently change the stored array.

Since I don't want redundant copies of the data, and just want to store the original data on disk, I thought I should use the `'c'` mode (copy-on-write) to open the arrays. But then where do your changes go? Are the changes kept just in memory? If so, if I change the whole array won't I run out of memory on a small-memory system?

Here's an example of a test which I expected to fail:

On a large memory system, create the array:

```
import numpy as np
GB = 1000**3
GiB = 1024**3
a = np.zeros((50000, 20000), dtype='float32')
bytes = a.size * a.itemsize
print('{} GB'.format(bytes / GB))
print('{} GiB'.format(bytes / GiB))
np.save('a.npy', a)
# Output:
# 4.0 GB
# 3.725290298461914 GiB
```

Now, on a machine with just 2 Gb of memory, this fails as expected:

```
a = np.load('a.npy')
```

But these two will succeed, as expected:

```
a = np.load('a.npy', mmap_mode='r+')
a = np.load('a.npy', mmap_mode='c')
```

**Issue 1:** I run out of memory running this code, trying to modify the memmapped array (fails regardless of r+/c mode):

```
for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    print('row {}'.format(i))
    a[i,:] = i*np.arange(a.shape[1])
```

**Why does this fail (especially, why does it fail even in `r+` mode, where it can write to the disk)? I thought `memmap` would only load pieces of the array into memory?**

**Issue 2:** When I force the numpy to flush the changes every once in a while, both r+/c mode successfully finish the loop. **But how can `c` mode do this?** I didn't think `flush()` would do anything for `c` mode? The changes aren't written to disk, so they are kept in memory, and yet somehow all the changes, which must be over 3Gb, don't cause out-of-memory errors?

```
for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    if i % 100 == 0:
        print('row {}'.format(i))
        a.flush()
    a[i,:] = i*np.arange(a.shape[1])
```

Comment: Regarding your issue 2, I tried your code snippet with an nd-array larger than the reserved memory in a docker container, and my process got killed after a while (probably due to an out-of-memory error), as expected. I used python:3.7.7-buster image with numpy version '1.19.0'. May you share your environment as well?

Answer (score 1):

Numpy isn't doing anything clever here, it's just deferring to the builtin `memmap` module, which has an `access` argument that:

> accepts one of four values: `ACCESS_READ`, `ACCESS_WRITE`, or `ACCESS_COPY` to specify read-only, write-through or **copy-on-write memory** respectively.

On linux, this works by calling the `mmap` system call with

> `MAP_PRIVATE`
>
> Create a private copy-on-write mapping.  Updates to the
> mapping are not visible to other processes mapping the same
> file, and are not carried through to the underlying file.

Regarding your question

> The changes aren't written to disk, so they are kept in memory, and yet somehow all the changes, which must be over 3Gb, don't cause out-of-memory errors?

The changes likely *are* written to disk, but just not to the file you opened. They're likely paged into virtual memory somewhere.

Comment: Is there a case that the changes can be written on the memory? I have tried an example where I modify the `mmap array` and the ram usage is increased but then decreased. I just did `y = 2*x` where `x` is a `mmap array` of very large size.